# DOM object in SOAP xml response as an object in __SoapCall display difficulties

Tags: php, xml, api, dom, soap

I am communicating with the API and I am getting the following XML result (checked in the logs of the API):

```
      <sfobject>
      <id>USR-3192</id>
      <type>User</type>
      <lastName>Lochki</lastName>
      <city>Gdynia</city>
      </sfobject>
```

But for some reason, when I am using __SoapCall in PHP and then want to display the results, the lastName and City get merged and displayed as one under 'any'? :

```
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'id' => 'USR-3192',
     'type' => 'User',
     'any' => 'LochkiGdynia',
      )),
```

Any ideas maybe? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Here's the code. I am logging successfully before.

```
$request1 = array( 

'query' => array(  
    'queryString' => "SELECT lastName,city FROM User WHERE firstName = 'Marek'",

                ),                  

            );


 $response1 = $objSoapClient->__soapCall('query', $request1);


 echo "<pre>";
 var_export($response1);
 echo "</pre>";
```

I have figured out that this 'any' is mentioned in the documentation as follows:

```
 any 
 List<Object>
 The list of the SFObject fields. The format is <FieldName>FieldValue</FieldName>.
 The list element is a DOM object.
```

How can I access it properly though?

As I checked the source, it displays it like this:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => USR-3192
        [type] => User
        [any] => <lastName>Lochki</lastName><city>Gdynia</city>
    )
```

How can I get it done?